# Not able to view CartoDB layer remotely

Tags: carto, remote-hosting, windshaft

I was able to login as

```
http://<domain_name>:3000
```

Done some import jobs, **publish** the map, copied the **API** link to a sample HTML page. Able to view the whole base map and CartoDB layer from local. But I tried from other network, the CartoDB layer seems to be not seen. Checked the console, but no errors where logged. Edited the development.js from the Windshaft directory and changed the localhost instances to domain name, and also the app_config.yml files.

Answer (score 1):

The local system browser knows about your `domain` just because you've added an `/etc/hosts` entry pointing `domain` to your localhost.

I see two ways for you to see your cartodb from a remote network:

a) accessing your computer using it's public IP, like this: `http://public_ip:3000`

b) having access to your **`DNS server`** and inserting `Address records` for your `domain` and for your `subdomain`, like this:

```
NAME                    TYPE   VALUE
--------------------------------------------------
domain.com              A      public_ip
subdomain.domain.com.   A      public_ip
```

This way, you'll be able to access your machine from remote using http://domain.com:3000

See also, **[this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cartodb/mydomain%2420local%7Csort%3arelevance%7Cspell%3atrue/cartodb/P5uGi_PYEDY/_tYL07qM_VYJ)** link.

Comment: I am been able to access cartodb dash board from remote using **http://<domain_name>:3000**. But still not able to load a layer, that is rendered using cartodb, from remote. I have using **cartodb.createLayer(mapObject, cartoframeLayerURL ,{no_cdn: true })** to create layer.

Comment: How looks your cartoframeLayerURL? Is something as http://domain.com:3000 or http://subdomain.domain.com:3000?

Comment: http://<sample>.no-ip.biz:3000/api/v2/viz/769ed96a-8c9e-11e3-a26c-dc0ea16343f8/viz.json

Comment: Did you have a firewall blocking the 3000 port on your "server"? Did you tried to disable it or adding a passing rule?

Comment: port forwarding is done for port 3000.